# how to build Android2.1 wid Launcher2

Tags: android

pls help me out in following matter,,, its esstentail for me..
I want to build android 2.1 with Launcher2 rather than default Launcher....for this , m taking following steps

---

1. i m changing the /buil/target/product   in this some . mk files , m changing on them Launcher to Launcher2.
2. I m removing or commentintg the 
              #LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
   in /frameworks/base/libs/rs/Android.mk  and /frameworks/base/graphics/jni /Android.mk

but everytime , while building n staring the emulator , its givng error tht fail to launch Launcher2 in emulator......

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with Launcher2. It throws the error UnSatisifiedLinkError. You need to comment out some part in Framework source